# How to pass custom headers in Atlas client

Tags: java, apache-atlas

I am using Atlas client v2 library to communicate Atlas server. How can I pass custom request headers using Atlas client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be this feature is yet to be implemented in Atlas client.

References
https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ATLAS/issues/ATLAS-3106?filter=allopenissues